# Simple maths is breaking jQuery UI Slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm pretty new to jQuery.  I'm an old timer PHP Dev and stuck my head in the sand for too long avoiding new front end technologies.

Anyhow I have finally given in.  I am using multiple jQuery UI sliders.  When 1 slider is changed I trigger the change event in the field that is being edited.

So when any input with a class `slider-total` changes I run this function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#slider-domains" ).slider({
        orientation: "vertical",
        range: "min",
        min: 1,
        max: 20,
        value: 1,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#domains" ).val( ui.value ).trigger("change");
        }

    });

    $( "#slider-diskspace" ).slider({
        orientation: "vertical",
        range: "min",
        min: 50,
        max: 5000,
        step: 50,
        value: 50,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#diskspace" ).val( ui.value ).trigger("change");
        }

    });

    $( "#slider-mysql" ).slider({
        orientation: "vertical",
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        max: 20,
        value: 0,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#mysql" ).val( ui.value ).trigger("change");
        }
    });


    $( "#slider-emails" ).slider({
        orientation: "vertical",
        range: "min",
        min: 1,
        max: 50,
        value: 1,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#emails" ).val( ui.value ).trigger("change");
        }

    });

    $( "#slider-ftp" ).slider({
        orientation: "vertical",
        range: "min",
        min: 1,
        max: 50,
        value: 1,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#ftp" ).val( ui.value ).trigger("change");
        }
    });

    $( "#slider-subdom" ).slider({
        orientation: "vertical",
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        max: 20,
        value: 0,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#subdom" ).val( ui.value ).trigger("change");
        }
    });

    $( "#domains" ).val( $( "#slider-domains" ).slider( "value" ) );
    $( "#diskspace" ).val( $( "#slider-diskspace" ).slider( "value" ) );
    $( "#mysql" ).val( $( "#slider-mysql" ).slider( "value" ) );
    $( "#emails" ).val( $( "#slider-emails" ).slider( "value" ) );
    $( "#ftp" ).val( $( "#slider-ftp" ).slider( "value" ) );
    $( "#subdom" ).val( $( "#slider-subdom" ).slider( "value" ) );


    $('.slider-total').change(function(){

            var ppdomain = 0.2084;
            var ppmysql = 0.05;
            var pphundredmb = 0.025;
            var ppemail = 0.028;
            var ppftp = 0.014;
            var ppsubd = 0.007;

            var nodomains = $("#domains").val();
            var mysql = $("#mysql").val();
            var diskspace = $("#diskspace").val();
            var emails = $("#emails").val(); 
            var ftp = $("#ftp").val();
            var subdom = $("#subdom").val();

            var total = 0;

            total = parseFloat(ppdomain * parseFloat(nodomains) + ppmysql * parseFloat(mysql) + pphundredmb * parseFloat(diskspace) + ppemail * parseFloat(email) + ppftp * parseFloat(ftp) + ppsubd * parseFloat(subdom));

            alert(total);

    });

});
```

The alert is just for testing,  but it doesn't work!!  Also it breaks the slider functionality.  The slides still update the inputs but the slide animation stops working.  When I remove this code all is fine again.

So where did I go wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem can actually be solved in a simpler way, you can't really trigger the `$('.slider-total').change()` event without really interacting with this field, you can though define it as a regular JS function like this:

```
function change(){
        var ppdomain = 0.2084;
        var ppmysql = 0.05;
        var pphundredmb = 0.025;
        var ppemail = 0.028;
        var ppftp = 0.014;
        var ppsubd = 0.007;

        var nodomains = $("#domains").val();
        var mysql = $("#mysql").val();
        var diskspace = $("#diskspace").val();
        var emails = $("#emails").val(); 
        var ftp = $("#ftp").val();
        var subdom = $("#subdom").val();

        var total = 0;

        total = parseFloat(ppdomain * parseFloat(nodomains) + ppmysql * parseFloat(mysql) + pphundredmb * parseFloat(diskspace) + ppemail * parseFloat(email) + ppftp * parseFloat(ftp) + ppsubd * parseFloat(subdom));

        alert(total);
}
```

For each slider, you already have a "change" event which is `slide` that is called once you change it, being that way you call the change function instead of trying to trigger it, like this for example:

```
slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#domains" ).val( ui.value );
    change();
}
```

Check this **FIDDLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/LNjGz/ for a test with only one field doing the math

**EDIT**

Cut this line out and the following ones:

```
$( "#domains" ).val( $( "#slider-domains" ).slider( "value" ) );
```

every `slide` event from each slider already set their respective text input so the extra work is not necessary

Comment: Hi G Mendes, I managed to fix it.  The change event isn't fired on the text inputs, because the changes are carried out by jQuery not user interaction (the interaction is with link tag of the slider.

That is why I am triggering the change event.  I managed to sort it either way,  but thanks for your input :-)